# How to center AND remove figure caption in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown

You can remove the figure caption with the forward slash

```
<center>

![](fig.png)\

</center>
```

But it ruins the centering.  How to center and also remove the caption?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `r-markdown` chuncks?

````
```{r,echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,
fig.cap="",fig.pos='H',fig.align='center',out.width='100%',fig.height=7,fig.width=7}
    #Load image
    knitr::include_graphics('/path/to/image.png')    
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Using the raw LaTeX rather than Rmarkdown syntax does this

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{fig.png}
\end{center}
```